# Update Password query in webpages_Membership

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm having an ASP.NET MVC 4 application with its default Forms Authentication implementation. I added some users and now I need to reset password for a few users in `webpages_Membership table`.

Is there a T-SQL query to perform this update? something like below..

```
Update webpages_Membership
set Password=....
where...
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do it in SQL, because the passwords are going to be stored in a hashed format.

In my opinion, you'd be best off doing it in code, using the methods of the `System.Web.Security.MembershipUser` class.  (Details and example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d94bdzz2(v=vs.110).aspx).)

Comment: You are correct. Had to use FormsAuthentication.ResetPassword()